# linking to named route with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show a user by id using the "link to" 
in my `users_controller.rb` I have a method show as shown below:

```
def show
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
end`
```

my route to this controller method is:

```
get 'users/:id/show' => 'users#show', as: :show
```

and the link to instruction is:

```
<%= link_to 'show it', show_path(id: user.id)  %>
```

the generated error is:

> undefined local variable or method `user'

I also tried this syntax:

```
<%= link_to 'show it', show_path(@user.id)  %>
```

but also I had this error:

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

but when I tried this :`<%= link_to 'show it', show_path(1)  %>`

it worked fine 
I am using rails 4 and I realy don't know where is the problem

Comment: Clearly @user isn't set. What matters is not your show action but the action that is displaying this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you have

```
<%= link_to 'show it', show_path(@user.id)  %>
```

?

I mean, it should be probably in users controller and index.html.erb, called by index action. If so, you didn't set @user variable. You can for example in controller set:

```
@users = User.all
```

and then in your template:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to 'show it', show_path(user.id)  %>
<% end %>
```